# Duration of service alert constantly changing on Nagios

Tags: refresh, state, nagios, duration

OK, so before I start, full disclosure: I'm pretty new to Nagios (only been using it for 3 weeks), so forgive me for lack of brevity in this explanation.

In my environment which I inherited, I have two redundant Nagios instances running (primary and secondary). On the primary, I added an active check for seeing if Apache is running on a select group of remote hosts (modifying commands.cfg and services.cfg). Unfortunately, it didn't go well so I had to revert the changes back to the previous configuration.

Where my issue comes in is this: after reverting the changes (deleted the added lines, started Nagios back up), the primary instance of Nagios' web UI is showing that a particular service is going critical intermittently with a change in duration, e.g., when the service is showing as OK, it'll be 4 hours but when it's critical, it'll show as 10 days (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fAZb.jpg) for an example host; the screenshots were taken less than a minute apart). This is only happening when I'm refreshing any of the Current Status pages or going to an individual host to view monitored services and refreshing there as well. Also, to note, this is a passive check for the service with checking freshness enabled.

I've already did a manual check from the primary Nagios server via the CLI and the status comes back as OK every time. I figured that there was a stale state somewhere in retention.dat, status.dat, objects.cache, or objects.precache, but even after stopping Nagios, removing said files, and starting it back up, and restarting NSCA, the same behavior persists. The secondary Nagios server isn't showing this behavior and is showing the correct statuses for all hosts and services and no modifications were made to it either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and in advance, thanks! I've already posted up on the Nagios Support forums, but to no avail.

Comment: This is on Nagios Core 4.0.7.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Never mind. Turns out there were two instances of Nagios running, hence the intermittent nature. Killed off both and started Nagios again and it stabilized.